# Why the NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i] does not add memory footprint in a for loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I am trying to reproduce the huge memory footprint in the for loop.For example, in a for loop like below, if there is not a autorelease pool in it. It will cause a peak memory footprint.

```
for(int i=0; i< 500000; i++){
    NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
}
```

Because the expression `[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]` return a autorelease object and if no autorelease is in the for loop, all the autoreleased objects will be released once, this will cause a peak memory footprint.
But as I tested in the Xcode6, this result was not reproduced. I used this `totalSize += malloc_size((__bridge const void *) test);` to calculate the total size of all the objects, but I got `totalSize = 0` result.
I can reproduce the huge memory footprint with the code like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", i];`.
Can some one explain this question, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Small `NSNumber`s (those that fit in 60 bit) are stored as tagged pointers. It's the actual 64-bit pointer value that carries the numeric value, so there's no heap allocation going on. This is done transparently for you by the Obj-C runtime. 
More on this topic: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-07-27-lets-build-tagged-pointers.html

Short `NSString`'s are stored as tagged pointers as well. See Mike Ash's excellent article on tagged pointer strings: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop you pasted, the `test` variable is created and immediately destroyed.
It belongs to the for's scope and since nothing else references it from outside, it will be automatically deallocated by ARC at the end of the loop.
That's why your memory footprint doesn't grow up.

Comment: This is often the correct answer, and ARC is pretty smart like that, but in this particular case, Tamás Zahola's answer is more applicable.

Comment: That would be true in C++, where stack objects are deallocated upon leaving the current scope. However in Obj-C, autoreleased objects are deallocated when leaving the current autorelease pool, which is a separate beast.

Comment: (I was saying that there's an optimization trick to avoid the autorelease pool, but I may be thinking of `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue` which solves a different problem. @TamásZahola is probably completely correct here.)

Comment: It would be interesting to see if using `[NSNumber numberWithLong:LONG_MAX - i]` would go the regular autorelease route, or ARC have other means of avoiding the autorelease pool.